# AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, pygame

So here is my code this my code and I don't know what have I done wrong is this code.

main.py

```
import pygame
import sys
from setting import Setting
from ship import Ship
class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.setting = Setting()
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.setting.screen_width, self.setting.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("ALien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.screen.fill(self.setting.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

I dono that could it be an error about my file location or not
import pygame

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        self.image = ai_game.image.load('images\spaceship')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Here is my error
this is what I got

> > > 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pygame\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pygame\main.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.ship = Ship(self)
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pygame\ship.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.image = ai_game.image.load('images\spaceship')
AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'image'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error should show you in which line you have problem and first you could use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: Why do you expect the `AlienInvasion` object to have an attribute `image`? Your `AlienInvasion` class does not even contain the word `image`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `__init__()` function of the ship class, you used `ai_game.image.load`. `ai_game` is here your `AlienInvasion` object. I think you intended to use `pygame.image.load` instead.